# Can we have a function of Brownian motion that has finite length?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

My thought was to consider $\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N |B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}|$. I thought that such a limit might diverge to infinity a.s., and I found a paper that showed that by simple contradiction.

Can we smooth out Brownian path or apply a function to is so as to make it have finite length?

E.g. is there an $f$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N |f(B_{t_i})-f(B_{t_{i-1}})|<\infty$ a.s.?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ would work, so you'll have to think more about what you actually want here. Besides that, it's a bit unclear what you're talking about. What are the $t_i$?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to keep some randomness, but just tamp down the variation enough to make the path have finite length. The $t_i$ are a partition of $[0,t]$

Comment: Well, there's a way to pick a function that "removes all randomness" so where do you draw the line? 'All functions' is too broad. It's certainly true that things like $f(x)=x^2,$ or really anything that has a nonzero derivative 'most of the time', $f(B)$ will be a drift diffusion and have a diverging absolute variation just like $B$ does.

Comment: That is aligned with my intuition, that most nice functions result in infinite variation.